# How can I modify column interspace in the legend of a lattice graphic?

Tags: r, graphics, lattice

I'm trying to create a figure in R with the lattice package.

The code I've written up to now is below:

```
myColours <- brewer.pal(12,"Set3")
    my.settings <- list(superpose.symbol=list(col=myColours, border="transparent"))
    png("test_fig.png", width=8.9, height=7, units="cm",res=300)
    xyplot(sim.values~obs.values, groups=factor(mean.df$month,levels=mixedsort(as.character(unique(mean.df$month)))),data=mean.df,
           ylim=range(mean.df$obs.values), xlim=range(mean.df$obs.values),
           xlab=list(label="Obs mean daily rainfall [mm]",cex=0.7), 
           ylab=list(label="Sim mean daily rainfall \n[mm]",cex=0.7),
           scales=list(cex=0.6), pty="m", pch=20,
           auto.key=list(space="top", columns=6, text.width=0, cex=0.5, pch=20),
           par.settings = my.settings,
           par.strip.text=list(col="white", font=2),
           panel=function(...){
                 panel.abline(a=0,b=1)
                 panel.xyplot(...)})
    dev.off()
```

What I get is the following image
[image]

The problem is in the legend, where the columns are too distant from each other and I can't manage to fit all the 12 months. Any idea to reduce the intercolumn spacing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `between` to your `auto.key` list.
For example,

```
auto.key=list(space="top", columns=6, text.width=0, cex=0.5, pch=20,between=.5),
```

or even `between=0`.

Comment: Thanks Dave, actually between is the command I was looking for. I tried with 3 or 4 columns but then the graph is a bit squeezed at the bottom.